# Using IBoutlet in constant initalization

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to use the IBOutlet mapView in MapManager. To realise this connection I have to present mapView to MapManager. I thought something like this would work:

```
 @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var userLocation: MKUserLocation!
    let mapManager: MapManager = MapManager(MapView : mapView)
```

Now, I wonder if this is a right way to do it. I mean, I am basically going to use mapView in a model which isn't the best thing to do. So how do I realise this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your code should not compile, because when initializing `mapManager` you are implicitly referencing `self`, which is unavailable until all class properties have been initialized.

I would solve that problem by defining an implicitly unwrapped `mapManager` property:

```
var mapManager: MapManager!
```

which is initialized  when `mapView` is set:

```
@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView! {
    didSet {
        self.mapManager = MapManager(MapView: mapView)
    }
}
```

Of course before referencing `mapManager` you have to be sure that `mapView` has already been initialized, otherwise a runtime exception will be raised.

Comment: Thank you! One design question; is this a right way to do it?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, but that depends on the specific problem. Often things can be done in more than one way. Basing on your input, that looks like the most logical solution though.